# mvc3 dialog box unable to reopen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog

I have a dialog box in mvc that opens up first time but not the second time and it gives me the error that the object does not support method dialog

this is my code:

```
     <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js") %>"   type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 $('.trigger').live('click', function (event) {
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var dialogBox = $("<div>");
            $(dialogBox).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: true,
                title: 'Test Modal Dialog',
                modal: true,
                width: 'auto',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                show: "slide",
                open: function (event, ui) {

                    $(this).load('<%=Url.Action("TabExample2","RQA")%>');
                             },
                overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 }

            });
            $(dialogBox).dialog('open');

        });
```

Modal Dialog

any advice on why this is happening?

Comment: This may just be how you pasted the code in, but you should have script tags around your javascript.

Comment: ok I found what causes this but not the solution yet, the reason is the dialog box is loading a view/page that includes jquery tabs, to create this I am referencing the jquery ui from scripts in that page and that is causing the 'object does not support method 'dialog'" error ... now my question (hopefully someone knows) how do I seperate the modal dialog reference to fix this problem... thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you don't re-referencing any jQuery libraries after you load Dialog Box.

**UPDATE**

To some calrification.
You should reference all needed libraries in heade section (or whatever place you want).

But to make tabs work withing DialogBox you need to write script explicity in that dialog box.
Just like any other in code jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  ///you tab code
});
```

This should work. I also had problem with not working tabs in DialogBox.

Comment: I will tag this as answer, although I have not fixed my problem yet but it is the re-referencing of the jquery ui library in the dialog page that causes this error when i fix i will add how to add the ui referencing to the master page...

Answer (score 0):

in this page you have solution and example:
http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/ 
and it's works :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but as you see in my code I do set the autoopen to false and then open the dialog, plus my issue is getting hte error 'Object does not support method 'dialog'" so somewhere along the line I assume the script reference of the jquery UI is being disregarded, what I dont understand is how is this happenening only the second time